# csvsimple and more filters

Tags: tables

how do I use csvsimple (or what else? pgfplotstable?) with more than 1 condition as filter (i need about 7) to show a filtered csv-file as table?
I tried things like:

```
filter=\equal{\gender}{m} and \equal{\grade}{5.0}
```

but that does not work. Example see below. Thanks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{testdata.csv}
name,gender,grade
Hans,m,1.0
Anna,f,2.3
Anton,m,5.0
Hilde,f,5.0
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lc}
\csvreader[head to column names,filter=\equal{\gender}{m}]{testdata.csv}{}
{\\\name & \grade} 
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{lc}
\csvreader[head to column names,filter=\equal{\grade}{5.0}]{testdata.csv}{}
{\\\name & \grade} 
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{lc}
\csvreader[head to column names,filter=\equal{\gender}{m} and \equal{\grade}{5.0]{testdata.csv}{}
{\\\name & \grade} 
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

[image]

the package seems to use `ifthenelse` internally so you can use that package's boolean expressions involving `\and` and `\or`.

So I just changed one line to:

```
\csvreader[head to column names,filter=\equal{\gender}{m} \and \equal{\grade}{5.0}]{testdata.csv}{}
```